# Copying text from CKEditor to Word change one particular font size?

Tags: fonts, ms-word, ckeditor, font-size

I am implementing CKEditor for one of my project. When I copy paste a set of lines with varying font size from MS word to CKEditor, then paste the same back to MS word. like this,

1. In MS word create multiple lines with different font size
2. Copy paste the content to Ckeditor
3. In CKeditor, copy paste the same content to MS Word again

All formatting is preserved except font size 11. Which get converted to 13.5.

In CKeditor, I have set

```
config.pasteFromWordRemoveFontStyles = false;
config.pasteFromWordRemoveStyles = false;
```

By default CKEditor use Px and we can customize it to use points or em.

My doubts:

1. What type of font size MS word use ? Points or Pixels ?
2. Why only font size 11 get change to 13.5 while other font size remain unchanged ?

Comment: Answer to question one : MS Word use "points" for font size

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar issue (with ckeditor, and word).

If the text in ckeditor is using the default font (ie you have not explicitly set the font, in my case arial), you select some text and change the font size to 12 points, and then copy and paste it into word, the font get changed to 11 points.

Note pasting into Wordpad and Excel, the font is correctly set to 12 points.

If you explicitly set the font and the size then it works properly (stays at 12 points).

My theory is that word is analyzing the html on the clipboard, and deciding to apply the word default font - (callibri 11 point), then changes it to arial, but decides to leave the font size as 11 points.